# Keeping a copy of all files in a repo while maintaining a .gitignore file

Tags: git, github

I have a Laravel repo that I am working on that is a git repo with the standard .gitignore files which I have modified slightly to meet the needs of the project.

Each time, I push the repo to github, all of the files needed for production are updated, but the ignored files are not. This presents a problem if I want to move to another machine and clone the project because some of the files i need from the first machine has not published those files.

Ideally, I'd like to maintain a repo that ignores all files, but also a repo of everything.

Is this possible either via git or another best practice?

Comment: What are the files? What is the reason for keeping them off the git repo if you would want them if you move to another machine?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear why you need to do this, but it can be done. You could have two branches, one which has files that are in the .gitignore

To set this up:

```
git checkout -b all-files
git add --force .                  # --force ignores .gitignore
git commit -m "adding all files"
git push origin all-files
```

Afterwards, after you make changes on your master branch and want to update the all-files remote:

```
git checkout all-files
git add --force .                             # only if you have updated ignored files
git commit -m "updating .gitignored files"    # only if you have updated ignored files
git rebase master
git push origin all-files --force
```

With this setup, master will only have files which are not in the .gitignore, and all-files will have all files regardless of `.gitignore`

If you would like to separate these branches into two different repos, it is as simple as making a new repo, setting it as a new remote using `git add remote all-files <URL_TO_REMOTE>` and using `git push all-files master` when pushing the all-files branch.

Comment: Hi @chenial - Ultimately, I want to make sure that my local repo is safe somewhere other than on my machine. I like the idea of using two different remotes. I suppose what I'm looking for is a good backup for everything that is within a git paradigm, but without pushing unwanted files to production.

Comment: Ah, okay. I usually just rely on a hard drive backup for cases like that, but to each their own. Does this answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The only files you should not put in the repository are the configuration files that contain sensitive information, settings that can be different on a different machine (paths, for example) or settings that can change without the need to operate changes in the code (the number of items to display on a page, for example).

The standard practice for such a configuration file (let's say its name is `config.txt`) is to create a version of the file that contains default values (empty for sensitive information like passwords) and comments that explain the possible values of the configurable parameters, their meanings a.s.o.

Name the copy `config.txt.dist` and put it into repository while adding `config.txt` into `.gitignore`.

When one checks the project out on a new machine he/she makes a copy of `config.txt.dist` as `config.txt`, fills the appropriate settings in it and they are ready to go.

The programmers must take care to keep their local `config.txt` in sync with `config.txt.dist`. Some frameworks (Symfony, for example) provide tools that create `config.txt` from `config.txt.dist` and update it when the project is prepared for deploy.

Replace `config.txt` with the name(s) appropriate for your project and the language(s) you are using to build it.